# Spring Boot TestRestTemplate: Pass along session id

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-boot, cookies

I've got a Spring Boot application with some tests.  The application's 'happy-path' requires that the user send a request to start a session, then it can make other requests to other services.

I'm trying to test these other services, but I need a session started first.  My mindset was as follows:

1. Hit the session start endpoint
2. Get the session cookie from that request
3. Slap that cookie onto future requests made during testing.

To achieve that, I've got this mess:

```
    String s = t.postForEntity(loginUrl, remoteSessionPacket, String.class)
            .getHeaders()
            .get("Set-Cookie").get(0);
    String[] split = s.split(";");
    String sessionId = "";
    for (String s1 : split) {
        if(s1.contains("SESSION"))
        {
            sessionId = s1;
        }
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("SESSION", sessionId);
    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    RemoteDTOPacket= new RemoteDTOPacket();
    packet.Token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/domain/SomeFunction";
    ResponseEntity<ResponsePacket> response = t.postForEntity(url, packet, ResponsePacket.class, httpEntity);
    Assert.assertEquals(0, (long) response.getBody().count);
```

Obviously, this doesn't work and errors are thrown with abandon.

Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session id is stored in cookie that is stored in "Cookie" header - not in separate request header. Something like this should work:

```
    List<String> coockies = t.postForEntity(loginUrl, remoteSessionPacket, String.class)
            .getHeaders()
            .get("Set-Cookie");

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.put(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, coockies);
    HttpEntity<Void> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
```

Or you can get exact session id cookie that will be most probably stored under "JSESSIONID" key.